# amqpnetlite link.Accept(msg) not dequeuing

Tags: amqp, amqp.netlite, amqpnetlite

I am using AMQPNetLite to send and receive AMQP messages from ActiveMQ brokers. I am new to this and would like to understand what I am doing wrong. I am following the example from the documentation as below.

```
        var _receiverLink = new ReceiverLink(session, "Name", "QName");
        _receiverLink.Start(10, (link, m) =>
        {
            link.Accept(m);
        });
```

I am successfully receiving the message but using of

```
link.Accept(m);
```

does NOT remove the message from the queue. Can anyone please guide me what I am missing.

Edit: It works when I add a delay. The message is removed from the Queue.

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
link.Accept(msg);
```

Comment: You would need to provide debugging details such as an AMQP frame trace from the client to determine what is going on.  Are you sure your application is staying alive long enough to actually send the accept frame?